# FileNotFoundException while uploading multiple images using Retrofit

Tags: android, file-upload, retrofit

I have a class that add a news with its images by Retrofit.
When Retrofit wants upload images, it shows me this error: FileNotFoundException
I have seen similar questions and answers but nothing was with multiple images.
So I could not find my solution and ask this question.
This is my Retrofit interface's method:

```
@POST("News/SaveNews")
    Call<GetResualt> setNewsLetter(@Body NewsLetterModel newsLetter);

    @Multipart
    @POST("Products/Post")
    Call<GetResualt> uploadNewsLetterImage(@Query("ProductID") String newsLetterId,
                                           @Query("CompanyID") String coId,
                                           @Query("UserID") String uID,
                                           @Query("Token") String token,
                                           @Part List<MultipartBody.Part> files);
```

This is my onActivityResult after image selecting:

```
ActivityResultLauncher<Intent> mLauncher = registerForActivityResult(
                new ActivityResultContracts.StartActivityForResult(),
                result -> {
                    if (result.getResultCode() == RESULT_OK) {
                        if (result.getData() != null) {
                            if (result.getData().getClipData() != null) {
                                int count = result.getData().getClipData().getItemCount();
                                int currentItem = 0;
                                while (currentItem < count) {
                                    Uri imageUri = result.getData().getClipData().getItemAt(currentItem).getUri();
                                    imageUriList.add(imageUri);
                                    partNames.add(currentItem + "");
                                    currentItem++;
                                }
                            } else if (result.getData().getData() != null) {
                                imageUriList.add(result.getData().getData());
                            }
                        }


                        NewsLetterModel newsLetter = new NewsLetterModel();
                        newsLetter.setActiveComment(false);
                        newsLetter.setActiveLike(false);
                        newsLetter.setActiveSave(false);
                        newsLetter.setCategory(category);
                        newsLetter.setCompanyId(BaseCodeClass.CompanyID);
                        newsLetter.setCreatorId(BaseCodeClass.userID);
                        newsLetter.setLinkOut("");
                        newsLetter.setLinkToInstagram("");
                        newsLetter.setNewsDescription(description);
                        newsLetter.setNewsTitle(title);
                        newsLetter.setShow(true);
                        newsLetter.setSpare1("#FFFFFF");
                        newsLetter.setSpare2("#FFFFFF");
                        newsLetter.setSpare3("#FFFFFF");
                        newsLetter.setToken(BaseCodeClass.token);
                        newsLetter.setUserId(BaseCodeClass.userID);
                        uploadNewsLetter(newsLetter);

                    }
                }
        );
```

This is uploadNewsLetter():

```
private void uploadNewsLetter(NewsLetterModel newsLetter) {
    Retrofit retrofit;
    JsonApi api;
    retrofit = RetrofitInstance.getRetrofit();
    api = retrofit.create(JsonApi.class);
    Call<GetResualt> call = api.setNewsLetter(newsLetter);
    call.enqueue(new Callback<GetResualt>() {
        @Override
        public void onResponse(Call<GetResualt> call, Response<GetResualt> response) {
            if (response.body().getResualt().equals("100")) {
                String newsId = response.body().getMsg();
                List<MultipartBody.Part> files;

                files = convertUriToFIle(partNames, imageUriList);
                uploadNewsImages(newsId, files);

            }
        }

        @Override
        public void onFailure(Call<GetResualt> call, Throwable t) {
            Log.e("Error", t.getMessage());
        }
    });

}
```

This is convertUriToFIle()

```
   private List<MultipartBody.Part> convertUriToFIle(List<String> partNames, List<Uri> imageUriList) {
        List<MultipartBody.Part> files = new ArrayList<>();
        for (int i = 0; i < imageUriList.size(); i++) {
            File file = new File(imageUriList.get(i).getPath());
            RequestBody requestFile = RequestBody.create(MediaType.parse(FileUtils.MIME_TYPE_IMAGE), file);
            files.add(MultipartBody.Part.createFormData(partNames.get(i), file.getName(), requestFile));
        }
        return files;
    }
```

And This is uploadNewsMessage:

```
private void uploadNewsImages(String newsLetterId, List<MultipartBody.Part> files) {
    Retrofit retrofit;
    JsonApi api;
    retrofit = RetrofitInstance.getRetrofit();
    api = retrofit.create(JsonApi.class);
    Call<GetResualt> call = api.uploadNewsLetterImage(newsLetterId, BaseCodeClass.CompanyID, BaseCodeClass.userID, BaseCodeClass.token, files);
    call.enqueue(new Callback<GetResualt>() {
        @Override
        public void onResponse(Call<GetResualt> call, Response<GetResualt> response) {
            if (response.body().getResualt().equals("100")) {
                Toast.makeText(getContext(), "خبر با موفقیت ثبت شد", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
            } else {
                Log.e("Error", response.body().getResualt() + " " + response.body().getMsg());
            }
        }

        @Override
        public void onFailure(Call<GetResualt> call, Throwable t) {
            Log.e("Error", t.getMessage());
        }
    });
}
```

So base on my code, at first application uploads news and other stuffs except of images, after that it uploads images.
But when it wants upload images it goes to onFailur of retrofit and shows me this error: FileNotFoundException.

Answer (score 1):

In  convertUriToFIle() use FileUtils.getFile(context,uri) instead of `new File(imageUriList.get(i).getPath());`